# Accessing microservice inside Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-network

I have a Dropwizard Microservice running in a container on port `9000`.

In the Dockerfile I exposed the port like so

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8-alpine

# Install packages
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash wget

EXPOSE 9000
```

Then I ran the container like so

`docker run --add-host="localhost:10.0.2.2"  -t foo-service`

However when I try to access it at `localhost:9000` I do not get a reponse in the browser.

How can I access the Microservice from the Docker host?

Docker host is Ubuntu 16.04

Many thanks

Comment: Normally you should run your container with something like `docker run -d -p 9000:9000 foo-service` but if I do this my container stops running and the error logs shows me: `[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle...`

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EXPOSE doesn't actually allow you to access that port from outside docker. It's a way of allowing other containers to access that port

If you want to be able to access port 9000 from your browser you'll need to add `-p 9000:9000` to your run command. This is a port mapping which maps your host machines port to the port on the container.